# Serial downvotes

Tags: support

Someone has downvoted each of my questions just now, I don't know why. Each had one upvote, now zero.

There aren't many, but I'd appreciate it if the culprit's actions would be reversed anyway.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Give it a day - it will fix itself. There are automated mechanisms in place to detect and correct this.

Comment: Two questions downvoted is not considered serial downvoting. There's no pattern. A number of down votes (more than one) means the item probably is bad. It's only 'serial' downvoting if 5 or more questions are downvoted once. (the algorithm for detecting serial downvoting may have a higher threshold.) So there's nothing to be fixed, those are most likely sincere votes.

Comment: You have no idea whether the same person voted on all of them, and until something is actually *egregious*, no action will be taken.

Answer (score 9):

As a new user, you are not attracting downvotes on reputation, so they are legitimate downvotes on content (or possibly random votespamming).

Each member of the community has a different idea of what a good question is, and votes accordingly. Some consider any question a good question as long as it is about English and reasonably clear. Others have different standards.

The owners of *EL&U*, in particular, intend the site to attract and serve English language experts (professionals and serious amateurs). As such, in their view, questions need to be well researched and interesting to experts. This is reflected in the FAQ.

Your questions do not show much evidence of research, and certainly do not go into detail about research results. Doing this in the future will help your upvotes.

The *vestigialities* question seems quite interesting despite the lack of research results, because it’s about a relatively new word that is still under the radar as far as lexicographers are concerned. The *said* question looks a bit interesting because of the various registers such as legalese that go into answering it. The word request for a noun version of *compel* is uninteresting. A word request is not a good fit for *EL&U* unless it's interesting to experts and well researched.

Comment: I agree with what Ed says here. In my comment, I mentioned the problem might "fix itself," but that's in the case of true serial downvoting, as happened [here](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/400/excessive-downvotes). In the case of 912, that doesn't appear to be what happened.

Comment: I didn't vote on any of OP's questions, but I'm certainly inclined to think *compel/compulsion* is GR and thus a bit too basic for ELU. And I personally don't like questions like that *vestigialities* one - anything that's in a dictionary is probably a word, and anything that isn't is just subjective. I don't know why *[the] said objects* got a downvote, but it was only one (and there are only two *upvotes* for the question, so it's obviously not captured much interest).